# Why is the text in the AppBar aligned to the bottom?

Tags: flutter

Why does it the text stay at the bottom? when i reduce the heigh of the appbar the text gets cut at the bottom.

[Aligned to the Bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD630.jpg)

```
class InfoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: PreferredSize(preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
      child: AppBar(
        title: Column (
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children:[
          Text('AppBar Demo'),
        ]
      ),
        //toolbarHeight: 10.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            tooltip: 'Next page',
            onPressed: () {
              openPage(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is the home page',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare in your Scaffold appBar COnstructor the widget AppBar() and not the size of your appBar. Go check Material.io to learn about designing for better customer experience.

```
return Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Column (
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      //Here you align the text of your appBar to the bottom
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children:[
      Text('AppBar Demo'),
    ]
  ),
    //toolbarHeight: 10.0,
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
        tooltip: 'Next page',
        onPressed: () {
          openPage(context);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
  ),
```